# Random BLANK textedit file generated -- '%A1%B1%A1%AF'

Tags: macos, random, terminal, text-files, textedit

I'm a rails developer seeking a fix to an annoying problem.
Recently, I've been noticing some random textedit file being generated in wherever directory I was working.
The file looks like this.
[Click this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wAUh.png)

After spending some time, I was able to find out that the file was generated every time I opened up Terminal. Even after I delete that random file, it gets regenerated if I open the Terminal app.

It says that the file is a TextEdit document, with 0 bytes of size.
When I open the file, there's no text.

It is so annoying because it gets tracked by git, and I have to delete it every time I am committing/pushing my work.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the causes why you have this bug, you can simply use a gitignore file to stop the file from being staged. You define a pattern and all files fitting will be excluded. It's generally recommended to have a gitignore to make sure no wrong files are staged.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But I'd love to just solve the root of the problem :)